# basic javascript function not working

Tags: javascript

I would like my script to check the textarea box when a user clicks on it and if it has the value "Add additional information here!" to make the box blank and change the text color to #000. it starts out as grey.

javascript

```
function changeMessage() {
    if(this.value=='Add additional information here!') 
            {this.value='';this.style.color='#000';}
}
```

HTML

```
<textarea name="message" id="message_input" rows="4" cols="21" maxlength="200"
            onfocus="changeMessage();" 
            onblur="changeMessageBack();"
            >Add additional information here!</textarea>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of `changeMessage()`, `this` does not refer to your text area. Try passing in your text area object like this:

**JS:**

```
function changeMessage(obj) {
    if(obj.value=='Add additional information here!') {
        obj.value='';
        obj.style.color='#000';
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<textarea name="message" id="message_input" rows="4" cols="21" maxlength="200"
            onfocus="changeMessage(this);" 
            onblur="changeMessageBack(this);"
            >Add additional information here!</textarea>
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/4K9p4/) to demonstrate.

**Additional Information:**

- [QuirksMode's explanation of `this`](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html).
- [MDN's `this` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: ya that works.  i thought this always refers to the element that it is in?

Comment: @noWayhome: It does, but your `"changeMessage(this);"` becomes the body of an anonymous function, so it's in *that* function that `this` refers to the element. When you invoke a function from inside another, JavaScript doesn't automatically set `this` in the function you're invoking to the current value. You need to do that manually. The [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9143288/1106925) from @xdazz shows how.

Answer (score 2):

When you called `changeMessage()` in global scope, the `this` refers the `window` object, while you can tell the runtime the value of this provided for the call to function by use [.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

Change `onfocus="changeMessage();"` to `onfocus="changeMessage.call(this);"`

Comment: @JamesHill: If you're down-voting answers for offering no explanation, then why just this answer? Why didn't you down-vote the other answer that offered no explanation?

Comment: @xdazz, Thanks for the explanation! I learned something new today :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the placeholder attribute without javascript:

`<input type="text" name="the_name" placeholder="Add additional information here!">`